# How to fill one of the two plane regions defined by a hyperbola with a colour?

Tags: fill

I looked for an answer in previous posts but I did not find it (sorry if this problem is already solved somewhere). I would like to fill with some colour the region on the right of the following hyperbola :

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\e}{1.3}   % eccentricity
\pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{(\a*sqrt((\e)^2-1)} 
\draw plot[domain=-2:2, ultra thick] ({\a*cosh(\x)},{\b*sinh(\x)});
\end{tikzpicture}
```

How can I do that ?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am probably missing something basic, but how about

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\e}{1.3}   % eccentricity
\pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{(\a*sqrt((\e)^2-1)} 
\draw[fill=blue] plot[domain=-2:2, ultra thick] ({\a*cosh(\x)},{\b*sinh(\x)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wooow, it was actually quite simple ! Thank you very much !!

Comment: I vote too il wooow :-) considerate that you haven't an upvote.